# TIMESTAMP_FORMAT option in FILE FORMAT object not parsing custom date string in Snowflake

Tags: sql, date, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When using the following TIMESTAMP_FORMAT in a FILE FORMAT definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT FF
     TYPE = 'CSV'
     FIELD_DELIMITER = '^'
     DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy/MM/dd'
     TIME_FORMAT = 'hh:mm:ss'
     TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'
     SKIP_HEADER = 1;
```

I receive the following error for value 'Nov 21 1946 12:17pm' when loading from a stage:

`Timestamp 'Nov 21 1946 12:17pm' is not recognized..."`

However, when using the TO_TIMESTAMP method it recognizes that string fine:

`SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('Nov 21 1946 12:17pm', 'MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'); Output: 1946-11-21 12:17:00.000`

I am referencing the timestamp formats on snowflake documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#timestamp-formats

Any ideas why this might be the case? Thanks.

Comment: How do you ingest the data? I made a simple test, and I saw that it works as expected.

Comment: I can reproduce that when trying to load from S3 stage. Even select from stage gives that error: SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP($xx, 'MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM') FROM @SOME_STAGE (file_format => FF);

Comment: When you use SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(x,'xxxxxx') FROM stage, the FF file_format does not affect this conversion - you already provided a specific format. So it should be related with the data. Are you sure that the value is "Nov 21 1946 12:17pm"? Could there be any space before the value? Or could it be related with the field delimiter? Can you share 1 line of your file?

Comment: Indeed, there was an extra space between data e.g. " Nov 21 1946 12:17pm" which caused the issue. It was misleading that snowflake didn't print that extra space but string already stripped. Thank Atil for help.

Answer (score 0):

To summary the issue, there was an extra space before 'Nov 21 1946 12:17pm', that was why the conversion failed:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('Nov 21 1946 12:17pm', 'MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'); -- works

SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(' Nov 21 1946 12:17pm', 'MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'); -- fails

Can't parse ' Nov 21 1946 12:17pm' as timestamp with format 'MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'
```